# how to delete element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, database

I'm facing an issue to fix a bug.

I'm getting data from dataBase. the data ( object ) contains an array of names.
I have useState hook that contains an array of objects. The value is names.
I want to delete every object from the useState hook that much the name from the array fetched for dataBase.

Exp:

```
response.data.players = ["player1", "player2"]

const [names, setNames] = useState([
{value: "player1", label: "player1"},
{value: "player3", label: "player3"},
{value: "player2", label: "player2"},
{value: "player5", label: "player5"},
])
```

I want the names become like this:

```
[
{value: "player3", label: "player3"},
{value: "player5", label: "player5"},
]
```

with minimum time complexity ( I'm already using .map to serve other hook with the names, if I can use it it will be perfect for the time complexity )

Thank you

Comment: a bug or code optimization with min time complexity? what are the contents of `.map`?

Comment: response.data.condidates.map((elem, index) => {
        dataCondidate.push(elem)
              })
this one is serving another functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just sounds like a filter to me. Can't you just do something like this:

```js
setNames(names.filter(name => !response.data.players.includes(name.label)))
```

For reference, here's that working without React:

```js
const names = [{
    value: "player1",
    label: "player1"
  },
  {
    value: "player3",
    label: "player3"
  },
  {
    value: "player2",
    label: "player2"
  },
  {
    value: "player5",
    label: "player5"
  },
];

const response = {
  data: {
    players: ["player1", "player2"],
  },
};


const filteredNames = names.filter(name => !response.data.players.includes(name.label))

console.log(filteredNames);
```

Comment: It is always a great option to make the code runnable.

Answer (score 1):

You can efficiently achieve the result using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const names = [
  { value: "player1", label: "player1" },
  { value: "player3", label: "player3" },
  { value: "player2", label: "player2" },
  { value: "player5", label: "player5" },
];

const players = ["player1", "player2"];

const set = new Set(players);
const result = names.filter(({ label }) => !set.has(label));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't use set before, it's new for me. Ill read about it.
Also i tried the code and it worked. I really appreciate your help:)

Comment: It's added in `ES6` and If you have a very large dataset in `players` then It is better to use the `has` method of `Set` to check for existence rather than `includes` of an `array`. `has` is optimized for checking existence. If you have a small data set then you can use either one. Happy learning 